# C# migrating files from MongoDB to Azure Blob Storage with "UploadFromStream" method not working

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm having problems migrating files from MongoDB 2 Azure blob storage.

The next method gets a GridFSFile object (which represents a file in MongoDB GridFSFileStorage) and then calls uploadMemoryStream method to do the upload.

It's worth to mention that gridFSFile does have content after findById and that length dows also has content and that position is initially in 0.

The gridFSFile.Open method creates a Stream object that I then pass as an argument to the upload.

```
private static void iterateOverVersionCollection(Version version, Asset asset)
{
    try
    {    
        string _gridFSId = version.GridFSId;
        GridFSFile gridFSFile = gridFSFileStorage.FindById(_gridFSId);
        if (gridFSFile == null) return;

        string size = version.Name.ToLower();
        asset.Size = size;
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = GetBlockBlobReference(version, gridFSFile, asset);
        uploadMemoryStream(blockBlob, gridFSFile, asset);
        asset.UploadedOK = true;
    }
    catch (StorageException ex)
    {
        asset.UploadedOK = false;
        logException(ex, asset);
    }
}

private static void uploadMemoryStream(CloudBlockBlob blockBlob, GridFSFile gridFSFile, Asset asset)
{
      Stream st = gridFSFile.Open();
      blockBlob.UploadFromStream(st);
}
```

UploadFromStream takes forever and never does the upload, and one thing to mention is that no matter how I work with gridFSFile, if I try to create a MemoryStream with it with Stream.copyTo c# method it is also taking forever and never ending so the app is getting stuck at blockBlob.UploadFromStream(st);

Instead of just passing gridFSFile.Open to UploadFromMemoryStream I've also tried the next piece of code:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048]; // read in chunks of 2KB
    int bytesRead;
    while((bytesRead = st.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        stream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    byte[] result = stream.ToArray();
}
```

But the same, program gets stuck in st.Read line.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that since UploadFromFileAsync() or UploadFromStream is not a reliable and efficient operation for a huge blob, I'd suggest you to consider following alternatives:

If you can accept command line tool, you can try AzCopy, which is able to transfer Azure Storage data in high performance and its transferring can be paused & resumed.

If you want to control the transferring jobs programmatically, please use [Azure Storage Data Movement Library](http://aka.ms/dmlib), which is the core of AzCopy.Sample code for the same

```
string storageConnectionString = "myStorageConnectionString";
     CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
      CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
      CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
      blobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().Wait();
      string sourcePath = @"C:\Tom\TestLargeFile.zip";
      CloudBlockBlob destBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("LargeFile.zip");
      // Setup the number of the concurrent operations
      TransferManager.Configurations.ParallelOperations = 64;
      // Setup the transfer context and track the upoload progress
      var context = new SingleTransferContext
      {
          ProgressHandler =
          new Progress<TransferStatus>(
               progress => { Console.WriteLine("Bytes uploaded: {0}", progress.BytesTransferred); })
       };
      // Upload a local blob
      TransferManager.UploadAsync(sourcePath, destBlob, null, context, CancellationToken.None).Wait();
      Console.WriteLine("Upload finished !");
      Console.ReadKey();
```

If you are still looking for uploading file programmatically from stream, i would suggest you to upload it in chunks which is possible using below code

```
var container = _client.GetContainerReference("test");
container.CreateIfNotExists();
var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(file.FileName);
var blockDataList = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>();
using (var stream = file.InputStream)
{
    var blockSizeInKB = 1024;
    var offset = 0;
    var index = 0;
    while (offset < stream.Length)
    {
        var readLength = Math.Min(1024 * blockSizeInKB, (int)stream.Length - offset);
        var blockData = new byte[readLength];
        offset += stream.Read(blockData, 0, readLength);
        blockDataList.Add(Convert.ToBase64String(BitConverter.GetBytes(index)), blockData);

        index++;
    }
}

Parallel.ForEach(blockDataList, (bi) =>
{
    blob.PutBlock(bi.Key, new MemoryStream(bi.Value), null);
});
blob.PutBlockList(blockDataList.Select(b => b.Key).ToArray());
```

on hte other hand if you have file available in your system and want to use Uploadfile method, we have flexibility in this method too to upload files data in chunks

```
TimeSpan backOffPeriod = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
int retryCount = 1;
BlobRequestOptions bro = new BlobRequestOptions()
{
  SingleBlobUploadThresholdInBytes = 1024 * 1024, //1MB, the minimum
  ParallelOperationThreadCount = 1, 
  RetryPolicy = new ExponentialRetry(backOffPeriod, retryCount),
};
CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConnectionString);
CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
cloudBlobClient.DefaultRequestOptions = bro;
cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(ContainerName);
CloudBlockBlob blob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(Path.GetFileName(fileName));
blob.StreamWriteSizeInBytes = 256 * 1024; //256 k
blob.UploadFromFile(fileName, FileMode.Open);
```

For detailed explanation, please browse

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/platform-as-a-service/azure-blob-storage-part-4-uploading-large-blobs/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Excellent and complete answer @Mohit Verma - MSFT. Thank you very much for your effort. I'll check it carefully as soon as I have time.

Comment: Glad to know it helped.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm not uploading a huge file but 3,000,000 of small jpg files and I'm trying to avoid writting to disk, what I'm trying to do is to read the file in Mongo as a stream and then upload that stream directly with uploadFromStreamAsync. The problem I'm having right now downloading, writing to disk and uploading (what works) is that it's extremely slow talking about such a huge amount of files, so I need to avoid writing mongo to file and uploading from file.